# How to turn off WAN captive portal on Asus RT-N66U

Tags: router, captive-portal

I have an Asus RT-N66U that I am using only as a local wifi router, i.e. it has no WAN connection. It does have an option to turn off the WAN port, but then if you go to any random webpage it intercepts the request and displays its own captive portal type page:

[image: captive page]

Does anyone know how to turn off this behaviour. It's bloody annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - turn "Enable WAN down browser redirect notice" off:

[image: solution]